# Moving of files from s3 bucket-A to s3 bucket -B with specific keys using python

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-s3

Bucket-1

- Name :audio
- Key  :2020/06/10/10/

Bucket-2

- Name : dev
- key  : source_metadata

Have to transfer files from audio bucket to dev bucket with options of specific keys using python

Comment: Code:import boto3

s3 = boto3.resource('s3')

copy_source = {

'Bucket': 'audio',

'Key': '2020/06/10/10/'

}

bucket = s3.Bucket('dev')

bucket.copy(copy_source, 'source_metadata')          ERROR: botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (404) when calling the HeadObject operation: Not Found

Comment: It appears that you are wanting to copy **multiple objects**. This is not possible. Each API call can **only copy one object**. Therefore, you will need to list the contents of the source directory, then loop through each object and issue the copy() command.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein Do you have any sample code for it

Comment: Yes. See the link to the duplicate question, at the top of this page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using new version of boto, then it is quite simple

```
import boto3
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
copy_source = {
    'Bucket': 'mybucket',
    'Key': 'mykey'
}
s3.meta.client.copy(copy_source, 'otherbucket', 'otherkey')
```

FYI: Docs: https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.copy

Comment: Tried this code, response says NULL and could not see any file in the destination bucket

Comment: Are you putting *key* value correct?

Comment: Destination bucket details in copy_source  and source details in otherbucket & otherkey right?